How to read this ceiling fan capacitor. What to replace it with. This one not available any more
This ceiling fan capacitor no longer available. How do I read the output 'ul's for each color wire?


Are you certain that the capacitor is faulty?

Yes, all of a sudden only 1 of the 3 speeds would spin fan. Never seen what looks like a series diagram. Did not know how to read it.
